# bootstrap input :required box-shadow override

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using *Bootstap 2*

I am looking for a way to override the red box-shadow on text inputs that have the `required` attribute set. The blue glow is nice on the non-required inputs but red seems too extreme.

I found the blue focus shadow (below) but I can't find the pseudo tag `:required` at all.

```css
textarea:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,  /*  HERE  */
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="datetime"]:focus,
input[type="datetime-local"]:focus,
input[type="date"]:focus,
input[type="month"]:focus,
input[type="time"]:focus,
input[type="week"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="color"]:focus,
.uneditable-input:focus {
  border-color: rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
  outline: 0;
  outline: thin dotted \9;
  /* IE6-9 */

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer after doing some additional research.
The CSS selectors stack - so to style the input with the `required` attribute set when focused you would use: `input[type='text']:required:focus{}`.
To override the red color and use a green color:

```
textarea:required:focus,
input[type="text"]:required:focus,  
input[type="password"]:required:focus,
...
.uneditable-input:required:focus {
    border-color: rgba(18, 140, 32, 0.6); /* green */
    outline: 0;
    outline: thin dotted \9;
    /* IE6-9 */

   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(18, 140, 32, 0.6);
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(18, 140, 32, 0.6);
           box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(18, 140, 32, 0.6);
```

}